# How to declare sql variable in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection

My requirement is to remove all record but **one** from a table. For this I am executing a series of two different `sql` commands. Seems like on `ssms` it works fine but with C# is not

```
--This is what I run on ssms without any issue
DECLARE @int INT;
SELECT @int  =  COUNT(*) 
FROM [Table] 
WHERE STATE = 'CO';

--Delete statement
DELETE TOP (@int - 1 ) 
FROM [Table] ;

public static void ClearData(string state)
{
    const string queryToExec = @"DECLARE @int INT;" +
                               "SELECT @int  =  COUNT(*) " +
                               "FROM [Table] " +
                               "WHERE STATE = @State;" +
                               "DELETE TOP (@int - 1 ) " + //NOTICE THIS LINE
                               "FROM [Table] ";

    List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>()
    {
        new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@State", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = state},
    };

    ExecQuery(queryToExec, param);
}

public static void ExecQuery(string query, List<SqlParameter> paramCollection = null)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand mySqlCom = new SqlCommand())
        {
            mySqlCom.CommandText = query;
            if (paramCollection != null) mySqlCom.Parameters.AddRange(paramCollection.ToArray());
            mySqlCom.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mySqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

My qsns

1. How can I declare a `sql` variable correctly in C# (see *ClearData* method)
2. And, how to execute multiple queries in a single query string?(if I am doing this right)

**EDIT**

I came up with this to accomplish this. But still now luck. Please advise me to what to do:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'uspWageDataByState', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE uspWageDataByState;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspWageDataByState
    @State NVARCHAR(2)  
AS

    DECLARE @int INT
    SET @int  =  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM [Test] 
    WHERE [STATE] = @State)

    DELETE TOP (@int - 1 ) 
    FROM [Test]
    WHERE [STATE] = @State;

GO

exec uspWageDataByState 'CO'
```

Comment: Better create a `Stored Proc` and call it.

Comment: @RahulSingh thanks for the suggestion. I cannot store anything in database and truth to be told I was sure it's not the best way. Can you please write me a stored proc for those two statement. I am not a sql exxpert and I need to do everything in my C# code

Comment: I can't repeat this - it works for me. Your declaration of multiple statements in a batch is fine - ORM's and Data access layers do this all the time, e.g. when preparing for `sp_executesql`. Good practice would suggest escaping column `[State]`, and explicitly setting `cmd.CommandType = Text`, but this is the default anyway. And as per Rahul, the proc is a good idea as well. Out of interest, wouldn't you also want to delete `WHERE [State] = 'co'` as well, otherwise you will trim all records?

Comment: @RahulSingh I created the stored pro you suggested but can't get this working please advise me what is the wrong

Comment: @StuartLC See the stored proc. Thanks

Comment: @RahulSingh edited. I was just debugging. You have got my point though? I was trying to get the count of row from first statement and pass that to `delete` statement but no luck either way

Comment: @Saifur - Your SP looks fine, what is the issue now?

Comment: @RahulSingh C# issue saying `CREATE/ALTER ` has to be the first statement. I will look into this tmrw. Thanks for your help Rahul.

Comment: I really don't understand why I got downvote for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your query (queryToExec) to:

```sql
    ALTER PROCEDURE uspWageDataByState
    @State NVARCHAR(2)  
    AS
    
    DELETE TOP 
    (CASE 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Test] WHERE [STATE] = @State) 
        WHEN 0 THEN 1 
        ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Test] WHERE [STATE] = @State) END -1) 
    FROM [Test]
    WHERE [STATE] = @State;
```

If the declared variable is the problem you can troubleshoot with this. It's not the best query, but your form wasn't either :P

I'm adding a 0 rows validation. In the previous implementation the stored procedure crashed when no data was found.

Answer (score 4):

I have run exactly this code in my environment and it is working as expected.

My framework version is 4.5.51641 and my SQL Version is SQL Server 11.0.2100

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace PruebasSQL
{
    class Program
    {
        const string ConnString = @"";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClearData("A");
        }

        public static void ClearData(string state)
        {
            const string queryToExec = @"DECLARE @int INT;" +
                                       "SELECT @int  =  COUNT(*) " +
                                       "FROM [Table] " +
                                       "WHERE STATE = @State;" +
                                       "DELETE TOP (@int - 1 ) " + //NOTICE THIS LINE
                                       "FROM [Table] ";

            List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>()
            {
                new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@State", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = state},
            };

            ExecQuery(queryToExec, param);
        }

        public static void ExecQuery(string query, List<SqlParameter> paramCollection = null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand mySqlCom = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    mySqlCom.CommandText = query;
                    if (paramCollection != null) mySqlCom.Parameters.AddRange(paramCollection.ToArray());
                    mySqlCom.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    mySqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

execute multiple queries in a single string statement :

```
string querystring = "select [yourcolumns] from [yourtable];select [yourvalues] from [yourtables]";
sqlcommand cmd  = new sqlcommand(querystring,yourconnection);
sqlDataReader reader = cmd.executeReader();
do
{
 while(reader.Read())
{
 //get your values here
}
}while(reader.NextResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 5, @PageNum   INT = 1
SELECT tickets.ID, tickets.userID FROM tickets WHERE tickets.isActive = 1
OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

in that way works in aspnet `sqlcommand` and `datareader`

Comment: 5 = row count in  one page, by the way you can add  parameter to the Page num                      and 1 = pagenumber